# Replaced outlets are tripping breaker

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

We are changing the color of the outlets in the kitchen from white to black.  We removed two outlets from the wall (*and took pictures of one to be sure to wire the new one correctly*).

Both are wired in series although I don't know how many more are in the series. When we turned the breaker back on, it blew immediately.
There is a red wire, black wire, ground wire, and two white wires for each outlet. The red, black and ground were easy to identify where they connect.

Is it possible that we may have switched the two white ones and does that matter?

Also, to be safe, before starting we turned off four breakers that were labelled "kitchen plugs". Only one stays on now, two of them trip immediately when turned on, and one of them trips the fourth one.

As both plugs each had 5 wires going into them, my guess is there are more outlets we have not touched on another wall that are also part of this series.

How do we fix these two so that the breakers don't trip?

**P.S.** *From now on we will mark every wire and its terminal screw!*

Comment: Did you remove the brass tab between the two brass screws?

Comment: Do you still have any of the old receptacles?

Comment: we did not remove the brass tab and we still have the old receptacles. I have the photos of the old outlets but they are not the best quality. it does not appear that the brass tab was removed from them. Unfortunately, the outlets are all at the cabin and I am now in the city without them so I can't check for sure until I get back there.

Comment: Yeah, this really sounds like a tab thing.  The 2 breakers thing also sounds like a **Multi-wire branch circuit** or MWBC.  Those are fine, however, there are special rules you must follow with those.   There's a tab on each side of the old receps; we're looking for the side with the brass screws (not silver).  Also did you turn off both breakers (the ones that tripped immediately) or only one when you worked on it?

Comment: This does sound like a multi wire branch circuit with a red and a black wire going to the same receptacle the tab needs to be broken on the hot side or the side with the red and black wire. 
The red wire is 1 leg of your supply and the black is the other a voltage measurement red to black will show 240v if the tab is not broken this is a direct short leg to leg. Break the tab and now each receptacle will be on its own circuit, I used to do this all the time prior to gfci’s being required.

Comment: i had turned off all of the kitchen breakers prior to starting the job.

Comment: I will check for this metal tab on the old outlet when i get back there tomorrow. How to i remove/break the brass tab if that's the problem?

Comment: Success! It was those tiny little brass tabs on the brass screws. Both of the original  outlets  had them removed. We did the same to the new ones and no more tripping breakers. Thanks!  